# EmberJS error deleting record from model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I delete an item from my database, I get the following error

```
Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on <app@model:mymodel::ember851:myid> while in state root.deleted.inFlight.
```

But sometimes the error change to:

```
Error: Attempted to handle event `notFound` on <app@model:mymodel::ember851:myid> while in state root.deleted.saved.
```

My model is:

```
export default Model.extend({
    position: attr('number'),
    name: attr('string'),
    shared: attr('boolean', { defaultValue: false }),
    color: attr(),
    textColor: attr(),
    permissions: attr(),
    calendarstack: belongsTo('calendarstack'),
    event: hasMany('event'),
    isActive: attr()
});
```

And my code to delete the record:

```
delete: function(type, id){
  var that = this;
  this.store.findRecord(type, id).then(function(data) {
    data.deleteRecord();
    data.save();
  });
}
```

Comment: This code looks good. Probably you access the model after/during the delete.

Comment: After deleting, a model hook is fired to reload the list where the element was. Could it be the error you are talking about?

Comment: You can use destroyRecord directly for the same right, instead of using deleteRecord and then calling save on it.

Comment: @EnriMR you should wait for the `.save()` promise to resolve.